# ComponentsBuilderFactory cannot be resolved

Tags: java, dependency-injection, apache-camel

Following the official documentation (https://camel.apache.org/manual/component-dsl.html#_using_component_dsl) I created this code:

```
package mygroupid.standalone;

import org.apache.camel.CamelContext;
import org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext;

public class MyMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        CamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext();
        context.start();

        ComponentsBuilderFactory.kafka()
                        .brokers("{{kafka.host}}:{{kafka.port}}")
                        .register(camelContext, "kafka");

        context.close();
    }
}
```

But the `Red Hat Language Server` in `VSCode` tells me:
`ComponentsBuilderFactory cannot be resolved`

And the `quick fix` feature in `VSCode` doesn't propose an import of a corresponding library.

Can someone point me to the right direction?
Do I have to understand the concept of `dependency injection` to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[As stated into the documentation that you are referring to](https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.apache.camel/camel-componentdsl), you need to add the next dependency to your project:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-componentdsl</artifactId>
    <version>x.x.x</version>
</dependency>
```

Where `x.x.x` is the same version as the version of Camel that you use

If you don't use any build tool like maven, gradle..., you can download the jar file [directly from the repository](https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.apache.camel/camel-componentdsl) and add it to your classpath.

---

Don't forget to properly manage your property placeholders `{{kafka.host}}` and `{{kafka.port}}` as described [here](https://camel.apache.org/manual/using-propertyplaceholder.html#_property_placeholders_referring_to_other_properties) or replace `"{{kafka.host}}:{{kafka.port}}"` with your target broker hostname and port.